# Exception chaining: What is proper way to get previous exception from the chain?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see that when I have a chain of exceptions, they are linked by `Exception.__context__` attribute that is a reference, to previous exception instance. But this is the result of my investigation. I haven't found any official information what is the proper and safe way to obtain access to previous exception in the chain. Is it correct to use `__context__` attribute? Is it possible to meet there something else than exception instance?

Comment: As far as [PEP-3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) concerns it's the proper way, but you might also need to use other attributes and/or variables like `__cause__`,  `exc_type`, `exc_value`, etc. For more information please read the PEP.